# How to solve this Error ??? raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) HTTPError: Forbidden

Tags: python, api, tkinter, urllib

I want to write a program that gets random images from the web using the api and then displays it using tkinter, but every time I get this error

```
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp

HTTPError: Forbidden)
```

this code works when I use other image links!  WHY ?  How can I fix this error ??

````
import requests

import io
# allows for image formats other than gif
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

import tkinter as tk

# Python3

from urllib.request import urlopen

root = tk.Tk()

url = "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search"


response = requests.get(url)
r=response.json()
URL=r[0]["url"]

image_bytes = urlopen(URL).read()
# internal data file
data_stream = io.BytesIO(image_bytes)
# open as a PIL image object
pil_image = Image.open(data_stream)

# optionally show image info
# get the size of the image
w, h = pil_image.size
# split off image file name
fname = URL.split('/')[-1]
sf = "{} ({}x{})".format(fname, w, h)
root.title(sf)

# convert PIL image object to Tkinter PhotoImage object
tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)

# put the image on a typical widget
label = tk.Label(root, image=tk_image, bg='brown')
label.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the mod_security or some similar server security feature that blocks known spider/bot user agents (urllib uses something like python urllib/3.3.0, it's easily detected). Try setting a known browser user agent with:

`headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}`

Full Code

```
 import urllib.request
    req = urllib.request.Request(url="http://localhost/",
 headers=headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    handler = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```